# How do I position my title on top of the GUI window?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlabel

I am new to programming and still learning. I need help in positioning a `JLabel` "Welcome back" on top of the GUI interface. The label keeps getting stuck in the middle despite my efforts. Feel free to correct any other mistakes shown in the code that I can do better.

[image]

```
public class MainMenu {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(30, 80, 400, 570);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 15, 15));
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    JButton meals = new JButton("Meals");  
    meals.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    meals.setOpaque(true);

    JButton reminder = new JButton ("Reminders");       
    reminder.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    reminder.setOpaque(true);

    JButton shop = new JButton ("Shop");        
    shop.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    shop.setOpaque(true);

    JButton sleep = new JButton ("Sleep Timer");       
    sleep.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    sleep.setOpaque(true);

    JButton account = new JButton ("My Account");        
    account.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    account.setOpaque(true);

    JButton aboutus = new JButton ("About Us");
    aboutus.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    aboutus.setOpaque(true);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome back!");
    label.setLocation(240, 20);

    panel.add(meals);
    panel.add(reminder);
    panel.add(shop);
    panel.add(sleep);
    panel.add(account);
    panel.add(aboutus);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(label);

    frame.setSize(480, 720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

Comment: **General comments:** 1) `panel.setBounds(30, 80, 400, 570);` This is both pointless and if it weren't, it would be counterproductive because it's just a guess. Instead, add the components with approapriate insets, border and padding, then `pack()` the frame to set it to its right size. 2) `new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24)` a) Don't include custom fonts in a layout example. But when you get to the stage of using fonts.. b) Don't use a specific font family without first checking it exists (there's no Helvetica on this Windows machine) - better to either use logical fonts ..

Comment: .. (e.g. `SANS_SERIF`), supply and load the font with the app., or check it exists and if not, use a logical font as backup, And .. c) Only create the font once. 3) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) `label.setLocation(240, 20);` Again, pointless. Position it using layouts and constraints, or in this case, simply use a `TitledBorder` for the panel with a `GridLayout`.

Comment: BTW - would something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlgHg.png) fit the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panels are rearranged on an intermediary Layout-manager(Border)
There are also various solutions based on Layout-used, but the main idea is the same

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MainMenu {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main Menu");
    //define a new layout
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //panel for label 
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(30, 80, 400, 570);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 15, 15));
    panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);

    JButton meals = new JButton("Meals");  
    meals.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    meals.setOpaque(true);

    JButton reminder = new JButton ("Reminders");       
    reminder.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    reminder.setOpaque(true);

    JButton shop = new JButton ("Shop");        
    shop.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    shop.setOpaque(true);

    JButton sleep = new JButton ("Sleep Timer");       
    sleep.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    sleep.setOpaque(true);

    JButton account = new JButton ("My Account");        
    account.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    account.setOpaque(true);

    JButton aboutus = new JButton ("About Us");
    aboutus.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24));
    aboutus.setOpaque(true);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome back!");

    panel.add(meals);
    panel.add(reminder);
    panel.add(shop);
    panel.add(sleep);
    panel.add(account);
    panel.add(aboutus);

    topPanel.add(label);
    topPanel.setSize(200, 30);
    //rearrange panels on frame
    frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(480, 720);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Output:
[image]